# Stored Procedure for tables data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables with the records

[image]

what is am trying to achieve to write a store procedure for retrieving data from these 3 tables like given below image  by joining these 3 tables.result should be as follows

[image]

so for i have tried hard but i am not successful.Help would be highly appreciated

Comment: is there a limit on the number of professions that an employee can have?

Comment: What part of the construction of the query don't you understand so that we can explain it? It might help to show what you have done and what the errors are

Comment: @ninesided yes employee can have only the same professions as in output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer

```
 Select E.EmployeeID, E.EmployeeName,
      STUFF((SELECT  ', ' + G.Profession
             from EmployeeGroups EG
             Inner Join Groups G on G.GroupId = EG.GroupId
             where E.EmployeeId = EG.EmployeeId
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') Profession
    From Employee E;
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Good luck with that answer. You will get this error: "Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed."

Answer (score 2):

You cannot perform in a join the kind of string concatenation shown in your sample output. There are two ways you can go about this.

1. Use nested cursors
2. Use a function that prepares the comma separated string and call it in a select statement

If you were instructed to use a stored procedure then use the former approach, otherwise the latter will be more efficient.

```
create function dbo.GetProfessionList(@employeeid int) returns varchar(max)
as
begin
  declare @prof varchar(50), @list varchar(max) = '';
  declare foo cursor for 
    select G.Profession 
    from Groups G 
    join EmployeeGroups EG on EG.GroupID = G.GroupID 
    where EG.EmployeeID = @employeeid;
  open foo;
  fetch next from foo into @prof;
  while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  begin  
    set @list = @list + @prof + ', ';
    fetch next from foo into @prof;
  end
  close foo;
  deallocate foo;
  --remove trailing comma
  return LEFT(@list,LEN(@list) - 2); 
end

select *, dbo.GetProfessionList(EmployeeID) as Profession
from Employee
```